# Java Polymorphism/Overloading surprise

Tags: java

Given this code:

```
class Task{};
class TaskA extends Task{};

class TopWorker{
  //... omitting constructor, instance variables, etc.
  public void work(Task task){
    this.subWorkerA.work(task)
    //followed by more subworkers...
  }
}

class SubWorkerA{
  public void work(TaskA task){
    // Subworker A does something interesting here
  }
  public void work(Task task){
    // Subworker A doesn't care, do nothing
  }
}

TaskA task = new TaskA();
(new TopWorker).work(task);
```

I would expect that the `TaskA` signature for `work()` would be called- instead, the `Task` version is being called.  I assume the issue is that `TopWorker` only accepts a `Task`, and so java must dispatch `SubWorker.work()` accordingly.

Is there any way around this problem? Assume that I have many `Tasks` and many workers, and the `TopWorker` is there to coordinate their results.

Comment: The method overload is chosen at compile time. All the compiler knows is that `task` is a `Task`, so the only method it knows it can safely call is `work(Task)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the `TaskA` signature is not being called is because `TopWorker.work` guarantees only a `Task` to be passed in and not a `TaskA` instance. `SubWorkerA.work(Task task)` ends up getting called because it's the only `work` method that takes type `Task` in the arguments.  If you instead call `this.subWorkerA.work((TaskA)task)`, the desired method will get called, albeit in an inherently unsafe manner.

I think you're probably confusing method overloading with late binding. Overloading simply allows you to name methods the same way so long as they have different numbers of arguments or argument types. When you call overloaded methods, the correct method is chosen based on the makeup of the arguments. In late binding, you override a method by duplicating its signature in a sub-class, which forces the overriding method to be called even if you refer to its parent object as an instance of the super class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the late binding vs. overloading; that's definitely the cognitive mistake I made.

Comment: Sure thing - a LOT of people have made this mistake, myself included :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround...

```
public void work(Task task){
    if (task instanceof TaskA) {
        work((TaskA) task);
    }
    // Subworker A doesn't care, do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Task` would better be an interface, at runtime you can figure out

```
public void work(Task task){

    if (task instanceof TaskA)
        this.subWorkerA.work((TaskA) task);
  }
```